# Extract data from a column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how can we extract the car model from the dataframe below:

Output:

2015 Maruti Swift VDI ABS........................... VDI ABS

2012 Maruti Swift Dzire VDI BS IV..............VDI BS IV

2013 Maruti Swift VDI......................................VDI

2012 Maruti Swift VDI......................................VDI

2010 Honda City S MT PETROL................... S MT PETROL

2013 Maruti Swift Dzire VDI BS IV..............VDI BS IV

2014 Maruti Swift Dzire VDI BS IV.............. VDI BS IV

2014 Maruti Swift VDI.......................... ...........VDI

2014 Maruti Swift VXI...................................... VXI

2016 Hyundai Grand i10 SPORTZ 1.2 KAPPA VTVT.............................    SPORTZ 1.2 KAPPA VTVT

2013 Maruti Swift Dzire ZDI..........................ZDI

2012 Hyundai i20 SPORTZ 1.4 CRDI......................1.4 CRDI

2010 Hyundai i10 MAGNA 1.2 KAPPA2......................MAGNA 1.2KAPPA2

2019 Maruti Vitara Brezza VDI ................VDI

2017 Maruti Vitara Brezza VDI OPT......................VDI OPT

2013 Maruti Swift Dzire VXI 1.2 BS IV..................VXI 1.2 B

2017 Maruti Alto 800 LXI...............................800 LXI

2009 Hyundai i10 MAGNA 1.2.............................MAGNA 1.2

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `numpy` or `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this dataframe:

```
                                          column
0                      2015 Maruti Swift VDI ABS
1              2012 Maruti Swift Dzire VDI BS IV
2                          2013 Maruti Swift VDI
3                          2012 Maruti Swift VDI
4                    2010 Honda City S MT PETROL
5              2013 Maruti Swift Dzire VDI BS IV
6              2014 Maruti Swift Dzire VDI BS IV
7                          2014 Maruti Swift VDI
8                          2014 Maruti Swift VXI
9   2016 Hyundai Grand i10 SPORTZ 1.2 KAPPA VTVT
10                   2013 Maruti Swift Dzire ZDI
11              2012 Hyundai i20 SPORTZ 1.4 CRDI
12             2010 Hyundai i10 MAGNA 1.2 KAPPA2
13                 2019 Maruti Vitara Brezza VDI
14             2017 Maruti Vitara Brezza VDI OPT
15         2013 Maruti Swift Dzire VXI 1.2 BS IV
16                      2017 Maruti Alto 800 LXI
17                    2009 Hyundai i10 MAGNA 1.2
```

Then:

```py
df["result"] = df["column"].str.extract(r".*?(\s\d{3}\s.*|[A-Z]{2,}.*)")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                          column                 result
0                      2015 Maruti Swift VDI ABS                VDI ABS
1              2012 Maruti Swift Dzire VDI BS IV              VDI BS IV
2                          2013 Maruti Swift VDI                    VDI
3                          2012 Maruti Swift VDI                    VDI
4                    2010 Honda City S MT PETROL              MT PETROL
5              2013 Maruti Swift Dzire VDI BS IV              VDI BS IV
6              2014 Maruti Swift Dzire VDI BS IV              VDI BS IV
7                          2014 Maruti Swift VDI                    VDI
8                          2014 Maruti Swift VXI                    VXI
9   2016 Hyundai Grand i10 SPORTZ 1.2 KAPPA VTVT  SPORTZ 1.2 KAPPA VTVT
10                   2013 Maruti Swift Dzire ZDI                    ZDI
11              2012 Hyundai i20 SPORTZ 1.4 CRDI        SPORTZ 1.4 CRDI
12             2010 Hyundai i10 MAGNA 1.2 KAPPA2       MAGNA 1.2 KAPPA2
13                 2019 Maruti Vitara Brezza VDI                    VDI
14             2017 Maruti Vitara Brezza VDI OPT                VDI OPT
15         2013 Maruti Swift Dzire VXI 1.2 BS IV          VXI 1.2 BS IV
16                      2017 Maruti Alto 800 LXI                800 LXI
17                    2009 Hyundai i10 MAGNA 1.2              MAGNA 1.2
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andrej. That was amazing.
Can you also explain the regex code above.

Comment: @KunalParihar Look here https://regex101.com/r/vkiD1u/1  The regex is explained better there and you can play with it online. (Basically, I search for part of the string that starts with two or more capital letters)